# A GUI frontend for a confusing command-line interface?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, command-line

Windows XP

The small company I work for just started using this command-line software and it's rather confusing and tedious. I was wondering if it would be feasible to make a GUI frontend and how I would start going about it.

If possible, I would like to have it get data to fill in dropdown boxes and such, but at the very least I'd like to be able to hit a button and perform whatever task. I have never done anything like this before so any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're not intending to do this in VB 6, are you? If so, why? VB.NET is a much newer, better, and more widely supported development platform. You can even obtain a free version of Visual Studio 2010 Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic) that will allow you to write programs in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

If the command line exe calls a dll or assemlbly to do the work, then you can work on a front end for the DLL based on the methods that it exposes (ie you can cut out the command line front end completely.

Alternatively you need to wrap the process that the command line runs in and catch its output, and pass it input as appropriate. There's a guide on how to write such a wrapper here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305994 (This one is based on writing the wrapper in c#).

One comment though - while it would be possible to do this in VB.Net using the illustrated techniques, doing it in VB6 would be much harder, or even impossible.